# String diagrams for bimonoidal categories (a.k.a. rig categories)?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, string-diagrams

I'm having some fun playing around with string diagrams for monoidal categories, expressing familiar constructions from Riemannian geometry and linear algebra in terms of elegant string diagrams.

I've been wondering if there is a nice extension of this diagram calculus to [bimonoidal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig+category) (also known as rig categories)? This would allow us to work with direct sums (of bundles, or representations etc.) diagrammatically as well.

Comment: There is a way to display direct sums in semisimple tensor categories. But it's basically introducing a basis. It's used for example in Sec .3.1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0204148 and it's sometimes useful in calculations in tensor categories.

Comment: @Peter Heinig thanks, I've changed the title. I originally had "string" in quotes because I was unsure if the graphical calculus for rig categories would involve strings or perhaps some sort of surfaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't anything like a graphical calculus really expressly dedicated to rig categories, and well-documented and proved to be coherent, but there are 'approximations' to what you are looking for:

**1. Proof nets.** The most well-known graphical calculus for categories with two 'operations' are

> [proof nets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proof+net)

though it seems not quite 'canonical' how they relate to string-diagrams in the most usual sense (graphical calculus for 2-categories).

**2. Graphical calculi for ologs.**

A recent preprint goes some way in this direction:

> [Evan Patterson: *Knowledge Representation in Bicategories of Relations*.     arXiv:1706.00526](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00526)

Therein one finds the following passage relevant to your questions:

[image]

(source: op. cit. p. 44; colors added)

Please note that 'distributive monoidal category' is *more special* than 'rig category' (the monoidal structure is assumed to by *symmetric*, and the symmetric monoidal structure is assumed to conincide with the category's coproduct), but it is relevant in that every instance of the former is an instance of the latter.

3. **Distributive laws via monads.** This is something I am currently only beginning to really understand, but I'll mention it here briefly: there is a notion of 'distributive law' formalized via

   - two specified monads on the same specified category,
   - one more specified natural transformation,

and such a situation can of course be formalized via 'usual' string diagrams; whether *this* is relevant to what you are looking I do not know.

Comment: In view of Cole's answer, it might be worth reconsidering whether this should be the 'accepted' answer.

Comment: @Todd I agree, though I guess ಠ_ಠ would need to contact you to ask for it...

Comment: @DavidRoberts To ask for what? He/she has the ability to unaccept and accept a different answer.

Comment: @Todd Hmm, I thought old accepted answers couldn't be unaccepted! If I'm wrong, then that's good to know!

Answer (score 13):

This question is answered in the affirmative in the following preprint:

- Cole Comfort, Antonin Delpeuch, Jules Hedges, *Sheet diagrams for bimonoidal categories*, arXiv:[2010.13361](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.13361)

The morphisms are represented by so-called proof sheets.

Here is an example of such a proof sheet, representing the controlled-not gate using the program [sheetshow](https://github.com/wetneb/sheetshow) which [Antonin](https://github.com/wetneb) created to typeset the diagrams in the preprint:

[image: controlled-not gate]

Comment: Thanks for adding this, Cole, and welcome to MO!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, David!

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for sharing.